# How can I connect to a FoxPro Database using Java and without paying?

Tags: java, odbc, foxpro

I was asked to connect to a foxpro database to pull some data. My biggest problem right now is finding an appropriate driver. Does anyone have any recommendations for free drivers. I know from my research on SO that this question has been asked before. I'm only asking again is that the questions are old and there may be a more relevant answer.

Comment: Did you try what the answers to those older questions tell you? And what is _old_ in your opinion anyway? - Besides that, you could list the answers you found and ask whether they are still relevant and/or tell us why you feel they might not be correct anymore or have become less relevant.

Comment: Sound like the work for some ODBC/JDBC driver.

Comment: What is old in my opinion? Anything more than 12 months is old to me. At least when it comes to tech...

Comment: Also, none of the solutions work. The links are either dead or not free. Google "stackoverflow java connect foxpro database"

Comment: Seems like one of [those "don't ask" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)...

Comment: What version of FoxPro was the database created with? Most importantly, VFP 6 or earlier (in which case there's an ODBC driver) or VFP 7 or later (for which there's an OLE DB driver, but that's probably less helpful to you).

Comment: Pretty sure VFP 6 or earlier. What is the name of the ODBC driver?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/visual-foxpro-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "Anything more than 12 months is old to me" this is why there are 6 million Javascript frameworks and the whole ecosystem is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a JDBC driver, that would be the way. I believe they expose ODBC, so you’d need a bridge which is what you’re likely trying to avoid paying for. Databases are collections of files on the file system so you could find and read the files using Java IO, and build your own parser.

As far as getting around licensing (paying), you probably want to turn on TOR, then ask the question again in another forum that has less respect for software licensing and the hard work and cost companies invest for professional software.

Comment: Open source software is a thing...No harm in asking if there are any open source drivers for reading a FoxPro DB.